# Outputting values from an NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm simply trying to output the values held in an NSArray as I want to see how big the thing is. However, I am very new to iOS development and object C in general so I was hoping someone could help me.

The array is filled with the following call:

```
-(void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager
     didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
            inRegion:(ESTBeaconRegion *)region
{
    if([beacons count] > 0)
    {

    } 
}
```

I've been playing around with calling the following line in side the nested if statement, but each time it is called, the system crashes:

```
       NSLog([beacons count]);
```

Can someone show me how to display the values inside this array and how I could possible go about accessing them?

Comment: Usage in this case is `NSLog(@"Array contents: %@, Object Count:%d", beacons,[beacons count])`. `NSLog` takes a string parameter, you are passing integer, hence the crash. In general, when in doubt use [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIJAAIA) as your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your NSLog statement is wrong it should be:

```
NSLog(@"%d", [beacons count]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"value stored in array are %d", [beacons count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
for (CLBeacon b in beacons)
{
NSLog(@"uuid: %@", b.proximyUUID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are technically correct, they don't do much to explain **why** they are correct and what the questioner was doing wrong.

Take a look at the function declaration: `NSLog(NSString *format, ...)`

`NSLog()` takes two parameters, a format string and a variable argument list (the `...`), which are used within the format string.

Format strings are literal strings that use format specifiers (placeholders) to substitute values into the string. Eg: `@"Hello my name is %@"`. Here, `%@` is used as a format specifier for an object, and will be accompanied by a name variable being passed in in the variable argument list.

The full function call would look like `NSLog(@"Hello my name is %@", myName);`

The format specifiers and variable argument list are processed in order from left to right.

There are other format specifiers for other data types (there are many more, so check the docs):

- `%d` - integers
- `%f` - floats
- `%@` - objects

The reason your previous code was crashing was because you were passing an `NSUInteger` (the return value from `-count`) as an argument to a function that expected a string. Strings variables are pointers in ObjC, so the crash happened because the code tried to access the integer as a pointer (you can read more into that in the docs).

Good start guides for iOS and Objective-C can be found at https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/gettingstarted/ and as always, read the documentation accessible from within Xcode!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableString * retStr = [NSMutableString string];
NSInteger n = [beacons count];
while (n>=1000) {
    [retStr appendString:@"M"];
    n-=1000;
}
if (n>=900) {
    [retStr appendString:@"CM"];
    n-=900;
}
if (n>=500) {
    [retStr appendString:@"D"];
    n-=500;
}
if (n>=400) {
    [retStr appendString:@"CD"];
    n-=400;
}
while (n>=100) {
    [retStr appendString:@"C"];
    n-=100;
}
if (n>=90) {
    [retStr appendString:@"XC"];
    n-=90;
}
if (n>=50) {
    [retStr appendString:@"L"];
    n-=50;
}
if (n>=40) {
    [retStr appendString:@"XL"];
    n-=40;
}
while (n>=10) {
    [retStr appendString:@"X"];
    n-=10;
}
if (n>=9) {
    [retStr appendString:@"IX"];
    n-=9;
}
if (n>=5) {
    [retStr appendString:@"V"];
    n-=5;
}
if (n>=4) {
    [retStr appendString:@"IV"];
    n-=4;
}
while (n) {
    [retStr appendString:@"I"];
    n--;
}
NSLog(@"%@",retStr);
```

Comment: seems like a lot of ways to do this, but, this is clearly the very most efficient way.